# How to determine mouse events in React Native (mobile)?

Tags: react-native, event-handling

I need to use a callback function for the mouse click event. Below code is working in React web app:

```
const checkAnswer = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const answer = e.currentTarget.value  // here .value property is undefined and gives error in React-Native. Just e.currentTarget is defined.
    const correct = questions[number].correct_answer === answer
    if(correct) setScore(prev => prev + 1)
  }
```

But I couldn't apply it on React Native (mobile) for `Pressable` or `TouchableOpacity`.

This is the render part of React web app's code:

```
<button value={answer} onClick{checkAnswer} />
```

and I try to apply it on React Native. The value will be passed to button's value. But there is no "value" option in native's Pressable component. Therefore I am confused

Any help?

Comment: What you want to achieve actually may I know ? Like onPress you would like to take what value ??

Comment: @TripleM actually this is the render part of React web app's code: <button value={answer} onClick{callback} /> and I try to apply it on React Native. The value will be pushed to button's value. But there is no option in native's Pressable's "value". Therefore I am confused

Comment: I'm in react-native around 3 years I can definitely help you out , but only 6 month in react so not able to understand your scenario. Just let me know what your current scenario - like are you want to click a button which is under a map function and you want to pick the value of that particular question. and want to update it in state.

Just let me know it, I will answer you with best possible solution.

Comment: @TripleM Thank you really bro. I am trying to take the value of the button clicked. There is such an option in <button> component of React (not native), but not in Native. I am trying to use the value assigned to the Pressable for deciding if it is correct or not, but there is not such an option in Pressable component. I am trying to find an alternative and handy solution for React Native to do that practically. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I'm preparing a answer with live example for you. I will post it in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

you can determine touch events by following

```
<View onTouchStart={(e) => {console.log('touchMove',e.nativeEvent)}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some similar scenario what I could able to understand from the question.

1. There is a **Score** state which will store the user's score of a quiz game.
2. There is a array of question where all the options and correct option are given.
3. There will be a button for the option, if user choose a option, and based on that it will validate if user is correct or not.

It might not be the exact scenario of you. But this could definitely help to solve your scenario.

Here is a solution for the scenario => [solution](https://snack.expo.dev/@mijanulg/basic_for_stack-overflow-answer).

If you click on the solution link you will be redirect to a page which is similar to the screenshot attached below. On very right you will find "My Device", "Android", "ios", choose any and run. Run via "my device" with expo app installed in your mobile if you don't want to be in queue for some certain time.

[image: code_image]

**Note**: from your code this is for React web:

```
<button value={answer} onClick{checkAnswer} />
```

but in React Native you have to use a click event like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>buttonHandler()}></TouchableOpacity>
```

Here `()=>` and `()` extra need to be added to work a function properly.

Also instead of `.map()` function you can use [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) to improve your app. FlatList support lazy loading.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this tomorrow and confirm your answer if succeed

Comment: Great, feel free to ask anything about react native if you stuck

Comment: can you look at my question here, the same question but more clear and more object-oriented. Can you post an answer there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73269066/how-to-pass-prop-with-the-pressable-onpress-attribute-or-with-any-other-attribut

Comment: Tip: if you need to use `inline code formatting`, you can (and should) use single backticks, not triple backticks. Triples (otherwise known as "code fences") are required for code blocks. Single backticks are easier to edit in inline formatting.