# How to pass prop with the Pressable onPress attribute or with any other attribute or any alternative method?

Tags: react-native, pressable

I am trying to pass the `answer` string (of mapped answers) into `handleButtonClick` function where I will compare the answer with the correct answer. Here is the code that is creating the answer string:

```
      <View>
        {answers.map(answer => (
          <View key={answer}>
            <Pressable
              onPress={handleButtonClick} >
               <Text>
                  {answer}
               </Text>                
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
```

And here is the code for handleButtonClick:

```
const handleButtonClick= () => {

  //check answer due to correct answer
  const correct = questions[number].correct_answer === answer;  // I am trying to pass the "answer" variable to here in order to make the comparison

  console.log("isCorrect = ", correct)

  //add score if answer is correct
  if (correct) {
    setScore(prev => prev + 1);
  }


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it like this:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => handleButtonClick(answer)} >
```

```
const handleButtonClick = (answer) => {
  const correct = questions[number].correct_answer === answer;

  console.log("isCorrect = ", correct)

  //add score if answer is correct
  if (correct) {
    setScore(prev => prev + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this before but it didn't work. But now works, therefore I accepted your answer